# Configuration.GetSection returns null in vs code, but not in visual studio 19

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm transitioning my .net core 3.1 app to run in VS Code instead of visual studio 19 and it builds and runs but I cannot read the appsettings.json file contents. It returns null.

In Startup.cs:

```
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

In my class:

var dbConnection = Configuration.GetSection("Database")["ConnectionString"];

here is what I see when I debug it in vs19, I clearly see the Data returning from my appsettings.QA.json file, but in vs code, it returns nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, it was an issue with the path in the launch.json

was:
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",

Needed to be:
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/ProjectName",

In visual studio, when I created the project, it doubled up on the name of my project. Now it works fine.